# Update multiple Azure Sql Databases

Tags: sql-server, azure

Currently, we have 12 Azure Sql Databases and typically 1 or more will need to be updated with a SQL query.

Today, I had a request to delete the same records from all 12.

Are there any tools or ways I can do this without having to connect to each one and running the query?

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/managing-multiple-azure-sql-databases-just-got-easier-with-elastic-database-jobs/

Answer (score 1):

Aaron Bertrand's [sp_foreachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) will let you do this by using the `@database_list` parameter.

Alternatively, there are third party plugins for SQL Server Management Studio that can do this, one which is [Devart SQLComplete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) but only in the premium version (which does have a 30 day free trial)